# About installing SimpleMathJax extension for Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, latex, mediawiki-extensions

I am trying to display *LateX* equations on a locally installed Mediawiki. I am trying to use *SimpleMathJax extension* instead of *Math extension*, since the former is used by sites like shoutwiki and seems quite easy to install and configure.

Following the instructions from [the mediawiki page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SimpleMathJax). It seems to work, except that I have some pages with a big number (500+) of equations and the render process becomes unstable: the page itself is quickly displayed but it does not render the equations. By manually refreshing the page, sometimes (maybe 20%) it does, and it takes around 10 seconds to display the equations: the text is shown on the page first, then the equations appear after around 10 seconds.

Now I am thinking of installing of MathJax on the server, but according to mediawiki, **MathJax is pretty heavy**.

My question is how heavy is MathJax? To display LaTeX equations is quite important for the purpose of my wiki page so I don't care if it consumes some resource, but is it affordable for a XEON E3 LGA 1150?

**P.S.**

In fact, I have also tried *Math extension*. In this case, to use the *Mathoid mode* as recommended by [mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Math), it seems I will have to run my own Mathoid server, since it seems external RESTbase is very slow to render my pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the one of the authors of SimpleMathJax.

"Heavy" means MathJax has many resources including styles, scripts and fonts(!). So, I recommended using CDN. But MathJax is much faster now. ( Actually, "MathJax is pretty heavy" was removed on the page https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SimpleMathJax . )

Which version do you use? If you use latest version, the performance can be improved. The latest version of SimplexMathJax is 0.7.3. It includes MathJax 2.7.3 (latest stable).

Comment: Thx! To be honest I am not very experienced with linux. As a result, although I have tried several methods (indicated by the mediawiki page), and none of them really worked. Also I cannot figure out the version of SimpleMathJax I was using by opening some of the source files in the extension folder, but I download a new version from the mediawiki link and realized I was not using the updated one. So I will try to update first.

Comment: Now I have updated the SimpleMathJax and run the update.php and it seems that the local problem with equation display is gone. PS: It seems that "MathJax is pretty heavy" is still in the README file :)

Comment: Aha! It was still there. I just edited REAMD file. "MathJax is pretty heavy" → "the benefits of using a CDN". :) Make sure using latest version or replace the directory with https://github.com/jmnote/SimpleMathJax/archive/master.zip (need to unzip).
PS: You don't need to execute update.php because SimpleMathJax is not related to DB.